# Rails: Howto get the controller generator add format.json call to all action respond_to blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could someone please remind how I get the generator to add the lines required to use JSON in my controllers? Having to type format.json  { render :json => @story } type lines to each action is starting to get old?

Comment: How would you know which variable should be json-ified for each action?

Comment: Exactly the same way as XML. I just want the generator to add the lines to save me doing it.

Comment: But the default action renders the action.html.erb file. Do you want to render the action.json.erb file or do a plain json return? In the latter case you should know which values you want to send to the browser.

Comment: Rails REST has two default representations HTML/XML, the default is HTML but XML can be used if I add .xml to the resource id in the URL. JSON can also be used by adding .json, but unlike XML the generator doesn't create the required lines in the controller, so I need to manually add a call to format.json inside every action block for it to work. All I want to know is if there is a way to save me a lot of typing and have the generator automatically add the lines required to deal with JSON? (As is already the case for XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to patch rails generator templates to handle this.  I know of no way to specify it